# what is the concordance index (c-index)?

Tags: statistics, analytics

I am relatively new in statistics and I need some help with some basic concepts,

could somebody explain the following questions relative to the c-index?

1. What is the c-index?
2. Why is it used over other methods?

Answer (score 0):

The c-index is "A measure of goodness of fit for binary outcomes in a logistic regression model."

The reason we use the c-index is because we can predict more accurately whether a patient has a condition or not. 
The C-statistic is actually **NOT** used very often as it only gives you a general idea about a model; A ROC curve contains much more information about accuracy, sensitivity and specificity.

[ROC curve](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/ROC-curve.png)